# How do i populate my recordset into my javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript, populate

Okay so where i put the ZZZ's it should repeat the next value in the row...

POPULATE VALUES INTO THIS PORTION OF JAVASCRIPT.....

```
categories: ['<?php echo $row_testresults['date']; ?>', 'ZZZ', 'ZZZ']
```

I can get it do do it like this.... on another page.. but I'm trying to make it work with a javascript chart

SOME WORKING NON JAVASCRIPT CODE.........

```
<?php do { ?><?php echo $row_TestResults['date']; ?><?php } while ($row_TestResults =     mysql_fetch_assoc($TestResults)); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($TestResults);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP object/array/string into valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting the date from each row to be in the javascript array? You're pretty close with your code, but I might do it like this:

```
<?php
$categories = '';
while ($row_TestResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($TestResults)) {
    $categories .= (empty($categories) ? '' : "','") . $row_TestResults['date'];
}
<script>
var categories = ['<?= $categories; ?>'];
</script>
```

Comment: Per @ThiefMaster, json_encode is probably the best way to get the array back to your page. If you have more values in your result row than just the date column you'd need to loop your set in PHP and build an array with just the date values. Then json_encode will get you your javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
functin getvalues() {

     while ($row_TestResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($TestResults)) {
        echo $TestResults[abc] .", "
     }

}

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo "var myCat=[". getvalues() ."]";

?>

</script>
```

Comment: Be aware that IE hates hanging commas on javascript arrays. Your code will result in an extra comma after the final value.

Answer (score 0):

I like what I'm seeing above, however actually pulling it off isn't easy... try to abstract the two things you're trying to do. First, hand code an example of what you want the HTML to look like:

```php
<script type="text/javascript">

// this is bad javascript, but relevant to his situation
series: [{
name: 'Tokyo',
data: [7.0,6.9,9.5,14.5,18.2,21.5,25.2,26.5,23.3,18.3,13.9,9.6]
}, {
name: 'New York',
data: [-0.2,0.8,5.7,11.3,17.0,22.0,24.8,24.1,20.1,14.1,8.6,2.5]
}, {
name: 'Berlin',
data: [-0.9,0.6,3.5,8.4,13.5,17.0,18.6,17.9,14.3,9.0,3.9,1.0]
}, {
name: 'London',
data: [3.9,4.2,5.7,8.5,11.9,15.2,17.0,16.6,14.2,10.3,6.6,4.8]
}]
</script>
```

I'm am going to assume that your data is in a 2 dimensional array. Meaning $row_testresults is in the form of `$test_results['London']=Array(3.9,4.2,5.7)`

Next assumption: that you've got a nice bit of data all tidied up in that $row_testresults. Check out this snippet:

```php
<?
function multiRow ( $sql ) {
    if( $sql == "" ) return FALSE;
    //echo "<hr>\$sql=$sql<br><pre>\n"; // \$row:
    $Q = mysql_query($sql);
    if( isData($Q) )
    while(  $row[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($Q) ) {
            ;//print_r( $row );
    }
    if( $row == "" )
            $rtn_stuff=FALSE;
    else
            for($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++){
                    if( $row[$i] == "" )
                            unset($row[$i]);
            }
    /*?>print_r( $row ): <? print_r( $row ); ?> </pre> <? */
    return $row;
}?>
```

If you do something like `$row_testresults=multiRow($TestResults)` or change $testresults for the actual query that generates all this data... then my code below makes life more simple:

Now, take the bit that repeats and put it in its own loop:

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
series: 
<?php
$java_data=array();
foreach( $row_testresults as $city=>$arr ){
    $tmpstr = "{\nname: '$city',\n";
    $tmpstr.= "data: [".implode( ",", $arr )."]\n} ";
    $java_data[]=$tmpstr;
}
$java_output="[".implode(", ", $java_data)."]";
echo $java_output;
?>
</script>
```

Mixing languages like this is probably bad form but it's great when you can pull it off. I personally have a tough time even with jQuery and Ajax doing all this in java, so since I'm super comfortable with php, I'll do the above before a dynamic ajax call.

I also find it crucial to use an editor with great syntax highlighting. In windows I use psPad and in gnome I use Geany. Back before KDE went v4, I used Kate.

Comment: I think that perhaps if you see it in context, I'm loading a graph.

http://fish.cutewhitecloud.com/graph.php

Comment: Im trying to get it to work... lol and i have about 10 text editors on my mac, I'm sure one of them will work.

Comment: Haha, that's awesome, I know the feeling. Check it out: http://lifehacker.com/5817833/the-best-programming-text-editor-for-mac

The other thing about php... that $row_testresults? To better understand it, try executing print_r($row_testresults) and/or vardump($test_results) so you better understand how to access the data. THAT determines how things work. See where I write $arr? That assumes the data in the array is an array itself! If it were the values in plain text, then you wouldn't implode it, you'd just use the text itself.

Comment: my problem is that: `<?php do { ?>
  '<?php echo $row_TestResults['date']; ?>' , 
  <?php } while ($row_TestResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($TestResults)); ?>` this gives me the output that i need, can i wrap this in a function or a variable and then try to get that to json_encode??

Comment: looking at your source again, try to use my helper function:

Comment: the above code outputs like this: '2012-03-30 00:00:00' , '2012-03-28 00:00:00' , '2012-03-20 00:00:00' , null

Comment: so... could that just be json_encoded or is the way you showed simpler?

Comment: lol the cities data is just placeholder data the data that i am trying to graph is just this

Comment: Check out the update. Also note that google has an api to do charting. Email me at ckelley (at) the domain in my profile and we can take this offline. :)